# Accidentally drop table in database that has no backup

Tags: sql-server

One Table is accidentally dropped in my database. I had not taken backup of the database since it is in development environment. I want to restore the table. Kindly please provide any solution. The last backup was taken 6 months ago. 
The table has related data to other tables.

Comment: Look at second answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91168/recover-deleted-table-from-the-database)

Comment: Hi Aaron, my question might seem duplicate. I know many of them have asked this question. But I have mentioned there that I do not have the backup with me.

Comment: If you have zero backups, then the table is lost. If you have some very old backup, then you might be able to restore, assuming that the database isn't in simple recovery model and never has been in simple mode since that backup and you have an unbroken chain of what log backups might have been taken since that old backup and assuming that you now are able to produce a log backup (BACKUP LOG) and then do a point in time restore to prior that accident. Not very likely, so the data is probably lost.

Comment: Sorry, the proposed duplicate was not the one I thought it was (it was [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/995/1186) - don't get thrown off by the title, what Brent's suggesting might work for any type of transaction - delete, drop, update, whatever). But there is no guarantee it will work at all, even with paid versions of tools, never mind free ones. Also, this is often an expensive lesson: backups are kind of important.